# Change the y-Position of a Text field in Crystal Report.

Tags: formula, crystal-reports-2010

I´m trying to create a Report with a lot of Fields.

I´ve some fields they could be empty. I´ve suppressed these fields with the formula.
The Problem is how can I change the y-Position of the next field.

Currently I have an empty field in my Report an that looks not so good.

I´ve seen it is possible in formula editor to change the x-Position of a field.

Can I do this with the y-Position too?

Regards

Thomas

Comment: So after asking in CrystalReportbook Forum, there is no Solution for changing the y-position of a textfield.

Comment: y Position means height, so the property Can Grow is not of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Either create a formula where you use the different options, and based on if they have a value don't show them, or create a different section for the fields that could be blank, and suppress them when empty